# Regex capturing block of condition

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
huile contains rgbgrbrb9gr && huile contains fcecec
```

I use this regex in order to capture a block of condition:

```
(.+) (contains) (.+)
```

It works with one block "huile contains rgbgrrb9gr" but if i add another condition with && or || operator, the two operators are captured.
What i'm expecting to capture if the two blocks excluding && and || operator.

Can someone have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?

Comment: First output: huile contains rgbgrbrb9gr
Second output: huile contains fcecec

Comment: **Side note**: regex is only suitable for matching lexical tokens. If you have a context-free grammar that you need to parse, you need to look for tools such as yacc or bison.

Comment: Additionally you might want to indicate which dialect of regex you're using. JavaScript RegExp? Perl-compatible? POSIX?

Comment: i'm working on Qt so i'm using qregularexpression

Comment: @Yanis600 Do you want to prevent matching `&&` and `||` or do you not want to match a `&` char and a `|` char? Can you add to your question an example what should match and what should not match? Do you want 3 capture groups in the result, or only matches?

Comment: I have the following filter string as an example:
'oil & blah'blah' contains 'oil&blah'blah' && 'oil & blah'blah' contains 'oil blah's'

What i want to catch is the following patterns 'string' contains 'substring'

the ' && ' or ' || ' must be excluded, and the pattern mentionned above has three matches
The & and | must only be captured in string i want to search and the string where to search

Comment: @Yanis600 Perhaps like this? https://regex101.com/r/taFZUP/1

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much :)

I assume that regex are really hard to built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex normally matches the longest input it finds.

You need to exclude `&` and `|` from your input, like this:

```
([^&|]+) (contains) ([^&|]+)
```

If you instead desire to exclude double-character `&&` and `||`, I suggest spliting your string based on those delimiters first, then matching using regex, as complex parsing is really beyond the realm of regex (they're grammars actually).

But, a regex solution is nontheless possible

The rough idea is that, you want to match a string with

1. an optional prefix consisting of no `&` or `|`
2. a single `&` or `|` followed by a non-empting string
3. repeating 2 for non-zero number of times.

the subpattern would be something like this:

```
(([^&|]+)?([&|][^&|]+)+)
```

additionally, you'll want something like the `egrep`'s `x` flag, to match the entire string, otherwise it'll be possible that an empty string turns up.

The full regex would look something like this (capture groups're re-numbered)

```
(([^&|]+)?([&|][^&|]+)+) (contains) (([^&|]+)?([&|][^&|]+)+)
```

Comment: it works but if i need to search for & or | operator, i got a wrong capture.

What i need to capture is for example:
'oil & other' contains 'oil &'

Answer (score 1):

After reading the post comments, the desired result was more clear.

This one could work too:

`(?<=^|(?:&&|\|\|) )(.+?) (contains) (.+?)(?= (?:&&|\|\|)|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/YDFpN9/2

Answer (score 1):

If you want 3 capture groups, you could match what you don't want first, and then capture in groups what you want to keep making use of a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach to not cross matching `&&` or `||` or the word `contains`.

```
\|{2,}|&{2,}|((?:(?!&&|\|\||\bcontains\b).)*) (contains) ((?:(?!&&|\|\||\bcontains\b).)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\|{2,}|&{2,}` Match either 2 or more pipe chars or ampersands (what you don't want to keep)
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:(?!&&|\|\||\bcontains\b).)*` Match any char except a newline if what is directly to the right is not `&&` `||` or contains
- `)` Close group 1
- `(contains)`  Match the word contains in **group 2**  between spaces
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `(?:(?!&&|\|\||\bcontains\b).)*` Same approach as above
- `)` Close group 3

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7lkJh2/1)